# How to get all simple products assigned to configurable products in magento 2

Tags: magento2

On product view page in magento 2 how can I get all details of associated products with image, name, qty box and add to cart button seperately for each product below details of main product?

Answer (score 0):

This line of code gets you the desired information in to product objects array:

```
$product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($product);
```

$product is a product model object which should be available in your product view page. Make sure that you check first if this product is configurable:

```
if ($product->getTypeId() == Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
```

From this point you need to loop over this array to render data in your desired way.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code gets you the desired information in to product objects array:

```
$product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($product);
```

$product is a product model object which should be available in your product view page. Make sure that you check first if this product is configurable:

```
if ($product->getTypeId() == Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
```

From this point you need to loop over this array to render data in your desired way.

```
foreach ($product as $info):
  $info->getName();
  ...
endforeach
```